# lost all my databases after reinstalling sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms

SQL server management studio was not working so, after googling this issue, I found that I have to reinstall it. So, after re installation, I lost my database and I didn't get a backup of it. So, is there any way to recover it back?

Comment: I just removed a table and imported the updated one. After that, the SSMS didn't connect to database engine. I tried several ways to fix the problem but it didn't work for me. So, I had to reinstall SSMS. After reinstalling I am able to connect to the server but can not see my database.

Answer (score 5):

**Background**

---

**Q1**

Did you reinstall SSMS or your actual database engine? Can you add a picture with what you are seeing?

**OP - A1**
[image]

**Q2**

Did you use the same login as before? If you reinstalled your database engine the database files might still be there. Can you check your default `Data` / `Log` folders to see if there are any database files there? If yes, you could try Attaching these databases again. What does this return? `SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin')`

**OP - A2**

> Yes, I use the same login as I was using before. I pasted "SELECT
>   IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin')" and run it on SQL query window and the
>   result is " no column name (1) nothing else. I don't know where my
>   database was saved to look on it if I can find any thing related to my
>   lost database. Could you please tell us where our databases would be
>   saved by default in C drive?

**Q3**£

This means that you are a sysadmin on the instance and that you should be able to see the database if it exists. You can try finding the system databases by using `select physical_name from sys.master_files where database_id = 1` and find  the default data path by executing `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('instancedefaultdatapath') AS [DefaultFile]`

**OP - A3**

> Yes, I found two files: LostDatabaseName.mdf and
>   LostDatabaseName_log.ldf. Now, how can I move them back to SSMS?

---

**Solution**

You can try attaching the database to your new instance.

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'LostDatabaseName',   
    @filename1 =   
N'C:\FoldersHere\LostDatabaseName.mdf',   
    @filename2 =   
N'C:\FoldersHere\LostDatabaseName_log.ldf';
```

**An example from Microsoft docs**

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'AdventureWorks2012',   
    @filename1 =   
N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf',   
    @filename2 =   
N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorks2012_log.ldf';
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-attach-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

I would also advise to not keep all your database files on`C:\` drive. If your drive fills up your server will crash and corruption can occur. It is also important to take backups of your databases, and putting these on separate locations.